# Phase transformation in shape memory alloy

Tags: material-science

As part of my MSc thesis I am using molecular dynamics simulation to study the pseudoelastic effect of Cu-Zr shape memory alloy during a tensile and shear tests. My question is related to the stress induced phase transformations during both tests.

During the tensile test I can clearly see a stress-induced phase transformation (B2 to B19') which agrees well with the literature but for some reason, I can't see any phase transformations during the shear test. In few words, during the shear test I can see an elastic region and a plastic deformation region with no phase transformations. Unfortunately there is no information on phase transformations in Cu-Zr during shear tests in the literature. My question is, why can we see a phase transformation during a tensile test but not during a shear test?

My interpretation is the following but I do wish anyone can help in case I am wrong. I am assuming that in the shear test the energy required for dislocation nucleation is lower than the energy required for phase transformation hence the alloy deforms plastically with no prior phase transition. The opposite happens during a tensile test,  where the energy required for dislocation nucleation is higher than the energy required for phase transformation, hence we can see the pseudoelastic effect before the alloy deforms plastically.
If my interpretation was the correct one it would mean that the energy required for dislocation nucleation changes depending on the crystal orientation where the load is being applied.

If any one can help explain why there is no phase transformation during a shear test but there is during a tensile test I would greatly appreciate it!

Many thanks,
Fabian

Comment: Did you shear it enough? Remember Mohr's representation of tensile vs shear stresses.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer. Yes, I am quite confident I did. The shear test I ran shows an elastic region followed by very little plastic deformation and ends up in fracture so I couldn't shear it further.

Comment: There is an algorithm in molecular dynamics called Common Neighbour Analysis that allows you to see whether there is any phase transformation taking place and it shows no phase transformations. However, in the tensile test the stress-strain graph shows the typical curve that you would expect for pseudoelastic effect and using common neighbour analysis I can confirm there is an austenite to martensite transformation. I am pressuming it has to do with the energy required to cause a phase transformation, which may be different in different lattice planes where I am applying the load.